# How to avoid user/perms headaches on VPS web server?

Tags: apache, permissions, vps

I'm using a VPS for the first time and I'm wondering the best way to set up this server that makes sense and has as little effort with permissions setting as possible.

So I use /var/www (all files owned by www-data) for system-wide stuff like PostfixAdmin, phpMyAdmin, etc. For actual domains, they're in `~/www/`. So my structure is like this:

```
~/
  www/
    domain1.com
    domain2.com
  logs/
    domain1.com
    domain2.com
```

The problem is, certain web apps like WordPress want many files to be writable, and the Apache user is www-data. I've found that even if I `chgrp -R www-data .; chmod -R g+w .` in a domain, WordPress still complains until the file is actually *owned* by www-data.

This server has no FTP and will allow me to SFTP in only via key, no passwords. I'm trying to keep this as secure as possible. But if I SFTP in, I'm creating files as myself, not www-data.

I'm looking for advice on how to set up this system so I can just drop in files, edit them, and all the permissions are what they need to be for Apache to have write permissions for whatever it needs to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Solution was to edit `/etc/apache2/envvars` and change these lines accordingly:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=myusername
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=myusername
```

And to also chown `/var/lock/apache2` to myself.